# Rate at which planet "sweeps out area"

Tags: angular-momentum, orbital-motion, angular-velocity

I want to show that the rate at which a planet circling around a star in an orbit is "sweeps out area" is $\frac{dA}{dt}=\frac{1}{2}r^2\omega$, where $r$ is the distance from the star to the planet and $\omega$ is the planet's angular velocity ($\dot{\phi}$ in polar coordinates).

It can be seen that the infinitesimal "wedge" area is $dA=\lVert d\vec{A}\rVert=\frac{1}{2}\left\rVert\vec{r}\times(\vec{r}+d\vec{r})\right\rVert = \frac{1}{2}rdr\sin(d\phi)\approx \frac{1}{2}d\phi rdr$ (since $d\phi$ is small).
Dividing by $dt$ gives: $$\frac{dA}{dt} = \frac{1}{2}\frac{d\phi}{dt}rdr=\frac{1}{2}\dot{\phi}rdr = \frac{1}{2}\omega r dr$$

Now, I believe, the next step is to integrate from $r$ to $r+dr$?
I think I'm probably complicating something. Would appreciate some help.

Comment: $d\vec{r}=r\sin(d\phi)\hat{\phi}$, where $\hat{\phi}$ is the polar direction. You can see this by parameterizing $\vec{r}$ in terms of $\phi$, and then taking its differential.

Comment: @ArturodonJuan: how do you parametrize $\vec{r}$ in terms of $\phi$?

Comment: In the plane of rotation, you can set the arbitrary phase of the rotation equal to zero and simply write $\vec{r}=r\hat{r}=r\cos(\phi ) \hat{x}+r\sin (\phi ) \hat{y}$

Comment: Can you please show how you get $d\vec{r}=r\sin(d\phi)\hat{\phi}$ from that? Also, this expression does not appear to lead to the correct answer.

Comment: Crossposted to http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1996879/11127

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

The area of this wedge, swept out by a Keplerian body in a time small time $dt$, is given by

$$\begin{align*}
dA&=\frac{1}{2}(r)(r\sin(d\phi))\\
&\approx\frac{1}{2}(r)(r d\phi)\\
&=\frac{1}{2}r^2(\omega dt)\\
&\\
&\implies \frac{dA}{dt}=\frac{1}{2}r^2\omega
\end{align*}$$

Going further, this rate is a constant. Let $m$ be the mass of the body in orbit.

$$\frac{dA}{dt}=\frac{m}{m}\left(\frac{1}{2}r^2\omega\right)=\frac{1}{2m}\left(mr^2\omega\right)=\frac{L}{2m}$$

where $L$ is the angular momentum of the body, which is a conserved quantity for central potentials (e.g. Newtonian/Coulombic potential).